# gmaps4rails infowindows (ruby/rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmaps4rails

How do I create a link to the current Class object using gmaps4rails gem?

I have specified the info window in the model like so:

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
    "<h3>#{address}</h3>"
end
```

However I would like to create a link to the object's show page that appears in the info window e.g.:

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
    "#{link_to 'Object' , object_path}"
end
```

However because this is within the model I can't use _path or _url.

Is there a way to do this from the controller or another easy solution?

***Update

Controller:

```
@json = Offer.where('state = ?', 'new').all.to_gmaps4rails  do |offer, marker|
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "offers/infowindow", :locals => { :object => offer})
      marker.picture({
                         #:picture => "http://www.blankdots.com/img/github-32x32.png",
                         :width   => 32,
                         :height  => 32
                     })
      marker.title   "i'm the title"
      marker.sidebar "i'm the sidebar"
      marker.json({ :id => offer.id, :address => offer.address})
    end
```

Infowindow view:

```
<%= link_to 'See Offer', @offer_path %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, [read the doc here.](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Controller)

Here is the example provided when you work in your controller:

```
@json = User.all.to_gmaps4rails do |user, marker|
  marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/users/my_template", :locals => { :object => user})
  marker.picture({
              :picture => "http://www.blankdots.com/img/github-32x32.png",
              :width   => 32,
              :height  => 32
             })
  marker.title   "i'm the title"
  marker.sidebar "i'm the sidebar"
  marker.json({ :id => user.id, :foo => "bar" })
end
```

I tend to put infowindow code in partials since its cleaner, but you're not compelled to use this abstraction.

---

I assume you use version < 2.x otherwise, the [relevant doc is her](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Json-builder)e and the method has changed.

Comment: Thanks v much. That is basically working, I just have one issue now - the link I created isn't linking through to the show view but is rendering the index. I can't figure out why - do you have any suggestions? Please see update.

Comment: this out of the question scope... but try `<%= link_to 'See Offer', offer_path(object) %>`